# jquery hover class change not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<html>
  <style>
   .highlight{
     background-color: pink;
   }
   .over{
     background-color: red;
   }
   .odd{
  background-color: lightgrey;
   }
   .even{
     background-color: gray;
   }
 </style>
 <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){ 
       $('.c').addClass('highlight');
       $('.a').addClass('odd');
       $('.b').addClass('even');
     });
   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>2: Zebra Striping Demo</h2>

    <table width="200" border="1">
      <caption><a href="#">UP</a> Zebra Striping Demo <a href="#">DN</a></caption>
      <tr class = "a"><td>January</td> <td>February</td><td>March</td></tr>
      <tr class = "b"><td>April</td><td>May</td><td>June</td></tr>
      <tr class = "c"><td>July</td><td>August</td><td>September</td></tr>
      <tr class = "a"><td>October</td><td>November</td><td>December</td</tr>
      <tr class = "b"><td>Monday</td><td>Tuesday</td><td>Wednesday</td></tr>
      <tr class = "a"><td>Thursday</td><td>Friday</td><td>Saturday</td></tr>
      <tr class = "b"><td>Spring</td><td>Summer</td><td>Fall</td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  <script>
       $("tr").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("over");
       }, function() {
         $(this).removeClass("over");
       });
  </script>
</html>
```

What i am trying to do in this code is have the color change to the .over css class when hovered. So basically, with the hover function, its not changing colors for all the rows . Only the c class row is being changed when hovered upon. Advice on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order of your CSS rules so that `.over` is last and has precedence.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.c').addClass('highlight');
  $('.a').addClass('odd');
  $('.b').addClass('even');
});
$("tr").hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass("over");
}, function() {
  $(this).removeClass("over");
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: pink;
}
.odd {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.even {
  background-color: gray;
}
.over {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<h2>2: Zebra Striping Demo</h2>
<table width="200" border="1">
  <caption><a href="#">UP</a> Zebra Striping Demo <a href="#">DN</a>
  </caption>
  <tr class="a">
    <td>January</td>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>March</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="b">
    <td>April</td>
    <td>May</td>
    <td>June</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="c">
    <td>July</td>
    <td>August</td>
    <td>September</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="a">
    <td>October</td>
    <td>November</td>
    <td>December</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="b">
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="a">
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>Friday</td>
    <td>Saturday</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="b">
    <td>Spring</td>
    <td>Summer</td>
    <td>Fall</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the *order* in which your CSS is being applied.

First, any tr with `.highlight` gets the background color (pink).  Then any tr that is `.over` gets its background color (replacing `.highlight`) and so on.  Note that `.even` and `.odd` are last.

Your two options are to either re-order your CSS declarations (as in @j08691's answer) or to make `.over`'s style be `!important`

```
    .over{
        background-color: red !important;
    }
```

Comment: I would *highly* recommend against using `!important`.

Comment: In this case, probably true.  I figured I would supply the alternative in order to have a more thorough answer that not only explained the cause, but provided both methods to fix it; you got to one before I'd finished typing.  There are valid uses for !important.